# Can a Virtual PC emulate a mac address for the network card too?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, microsoft-virtual-pc, mac-address

Can a Virtual PC emulate a mac address for the network card too?  It probably is possible but I think the Virtual PC / VirtualBox / VMWare / Parallel, all probably won't support it as the mac address is supposed to be unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done in [Virtual PC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708285%28WS.10%29.aspx), [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/support/esx21/doc/esx21admin_MACaddress.html), [VirtualBox](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=19266) and [Parallels](http://kb.parallels.com/en/729).

All the VM apps allow this, because VMs are often used to test network configurations and being able to simulate machines with specific MAC addresses can be useful.